# How to print to console windows?

Tags: windows, go, stdout, stdin

I want to run my go program from cmd like this:

```
 C:\go\awesomeProject> goprogramm.exe -generate -val=2
```

and want to get some feedback like this:

```
> Process started
> Something went wrong. Type e-mail to receive report:
> |...
```

Yeah, I googled a lot. Standard output, go exec'ing, pipes and etc. Just can't mix it up.

Comment: This is covered in the first page of the Go tour: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to use the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, and its global functions, e.g.:

```
fmt.Println("Process started")
fmt.Println("Something went wrong. Type e-mail to receive report:")

var i int = 3
var err error = io.Eof
fmt.Printf("And some formatted text: number: %d, an error: %v\n", i, err)
```

If you want more configuration or the option to redirect the output e.g. to a file (in the future), then you may use the [`log`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package.

```
log.Println("Process started")
log.Println("Something went wrong. Type e-mail to receive report:")

var i int = 3
var err error = io.Eof
log.Printf("And some formatted text: number: %d, an error: %v", i, err)
```

One notable difference is that by default the `fmt` package writes to `os.Stdout`, and the `log` package writes to `os.Stderr`. Both appear in your console, but should not be forgotten if you want to redirect those streams. Another difference is that the `log` package appends a newline to each call if it doesn't end with one.

Comment: How to redirect it to cmd?

Comment: The output will appear in your window without any redirection. I mentioned redirection as you may get different output when redirecting standard output or standard error based on which package you used.

Comment: Yeah, output appears in my IDE [console](https://i.imgur.com/m1yUr6Q.png). But it doesn't appear when I run exe from [command line](https://i.imgur.com/NX9pbh4.png)

Comment: @StayCool Are you sure you rebuilt and running the latest version of your app? First try runnig it with `go run appname.go` so it always recompiles.